# How do I access a table that has a composite key I can't model using Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an existing database that I cannot change, but want to access using EF. For 90% of the database, I have been able to get Code First EF to work, and I am very impressed.

I've run into a case that I am wondering how to model or access the data through a navigation property.

In one case, the tables are like this (this example is totally made up, but represents the problem):

```
CREATE TABLE Dog (
    id            INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    breed_id      INTEGER      NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Breed (
    id               INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    organization_id  INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    description      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    Primary key (id, organization)
);

CREATE TABLE Organization (
    id            INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
    description   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

In Table breed, the organization represents an organization that has defined a breed. A dog can have several breeds, but the program only displays one, the results being 'filtered' by the organization id - which is a value that is configured when the program is set up.

An example of the data that might be present is this:

```
id    organizationID    Description
 1                 1    Basset Hound
 2                 1    Great Dane
 2                 2    Grande Dane
```

Where organization 2 has chosen to call the breed something different than organization 1.  The unique primary key is a combination of id and organizationID.  A dog has a breed, but  does not have a property to define one or more associated organizations.  It takes additional information from another table, or a configured value (perhaps an enumerated value) to find the breed of a dog.

In my case, to find a particular dog breed, you have to have a dog id and another piece of information (organization_id) which is related to program configuration.

The dog, breed and organization classes look like this:

```
public class Dog {
  public int id  { get; set; };
  public string name  { get; set; };
  public int breedID  { get; set; };

  public virtual Breed { get; set; }           
}

public class Breed {
  public int id  { get; set; };
  public int organizationID  { get; set; };            
  public string description  { get; set; };

  public virtual Organization { get; set; }  
}

public class Organization {
  public int id  { get; set; };
  public string description  { get; set; };
}
```

As seen in the code, I'd like to use a "Navigation" Property on Dog that returns a breed, but don't think I can configure this in code first.

I've tried a few different things (in fluent API, and leaving organization out - since that's easy) and will also document things I don't think work:

```
1) 
   modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasKey(t => t.id);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Breed>().HasKey(t => t.id);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasRequired(d => d.Breed).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.breedID);
```

Of course, the problem with this is that more than one breed will be returned and entity framework will throw an exception because the breedID itself is insufficient to yield a single value - which the model is calling for.

```
2) 
   Change class dog:
      Remove:
          public virtual Breed { get; set; }
      Add:
          public virtual ICollection<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }

          public Breed Breed {
            get {
              // Assume 1 is configured organization value
              return Breeds.Single(t => t.OrganizationId == 1);
            };
            set {
              Breeds.Add(value);
            }
          }

     Change model:
        I don't know how to do this for the given classes.  Since it's a Collection, it must look something like

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasMany(d => d.Breeds)...

        but I don't see how to specify that breedID is a foriegn key into the breed table.
```

If I could get the model to work, the rest will work, but it does seem wierd and inefficient.

```
 3)
    Change model to account for composite key (using first set of classes):
       modelBuilder.Entity<Breed>().HasKey(b => new { b.id, b.organizationId });

       modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().HasRequired(t => t.Breed).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => new { t.breedID, configuredValue });
```

I don't know how to "inject" configuredValue as in the last line, so this doesn't work either.

If none of the above methods work, or if I can't find another way to configure code first properly, then I'd like to specify that when the Breed navigation property getter is called, it should use a query that can get the appropriate breed and return it appropriately.

However, I don't want to dirty my POCO with the Context calls to return the result of the query. In other words, I'd like to have a property on Dog that does NOT look something like this:

```
public Breed Breed {
   get {
      return context.Breed.Where(b => b.id == this.id && b.organizationID == 1).Single();
   }
}
```

Ideally, it would work like the Navigation collections do, where EF does it's magic and returns the appropriate results.

Intuitively, it seems like I should be able to either configure this using POCO-like code or use/extend a proxy to extend the configuration to use the particular query I want when the accessor is called. Or - it seems like I ought to be able to populate the property on any read and dirty the POCO on write. I'm just not familiar enough with EF to know how to do this.

Is this possible?

As an addition to the first post, because I desire to keep my POCO classes clean, I think I will probably implement the Repository pattern to encapsulate the complex queries like the ones I've described, as well as support other operations also.

Looking at the EDMX that I've generated from my Code First model, it's not apparent how to implement the model from a database first perspective, either.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That would be great.  Can you show me an example of how to do this for my example?  Thanks!

Comment: I tried to configure this, but didn't have any luck.  I tried a few things that looked something like this : HasRequired(t => new { t.typeId, otherVariable }).HasOptional()...   The problem is that I don't know how to "inject" the other component of the composite key when it is not a part of the "Dog" table.   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, I see the rest of your situation now, and the way I do it doesn't help you with that rest. Is the other ID to use stored somewhere in the database, or does only the program know about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, only the program knows it - it's part of the way the program that originally used the database works.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Good Q, It would be helpful if you could paste some code that represents your problem.

Comment: I reworked my question so that it is clearer and added code to illustrate my approaches.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have an existing database, then code first isn't the best choice. You should use database first. The clue's in the name

Comment: What exception did you received in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do that. You have illogical database structure (foreign key referencing non-unique column), you'll have to map it somewhere. You can't do that in EF configuration, because it's dynamic, so you'll have to do that inside you entity classes. And I see no ways to do that without direct call to context inside your entity class (or helper class).

Comment: Given that is the case, is there a way to invoke a particular query when the accessor for Breed is called?  I'm wondering if I can supplement Code First (which has worked out very well thus far) with POCO-like EF.

Comment: No, you'll have to do it yourself, something like the code you've already included in post.